# Exclude date from DateTimeField in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So I have a model that has a dateField and a dateTimeField. What I want is de Django database to exclude the date field from the dateTimeField.

My models.py

```
class WordTable(models.Model):
   session_ID = models.IntegerField()
   user_ID = models.IntegerField()
   date = models.DateField()
   hour = models.DateTimeField()
   run_label = models.BooleanField()
   status = models.BooleanField()
```

As you can see I have a date and an hour field. What I want is the hour field only to show the hour. How can I format that field to do what I want? help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want to render only the hour of the date time field in the template?

Comment: Is TimeField what you are looking for? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#timefield

Comment: Yes, I am pretty new to Django and I didn't know I could use that time of field, thanks! @Hisham___Pak

Comment: @enekovalero No problem added an answer so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only store Time you can use `TimeField` [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#timefield) instead of using `DateTimeField` which does not store a date with it.

### TimeField

> `class TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, **options)`
> A time, represented in Python by a `datetime.time` instance. Accepts the same auto-population options as DateField.
> The default form widget for this field is a TimeInput. The admin adds some JavaScript shortcuts.